# Get purchased iTunes music on linux

Tags: linux, itunes, download, music, wine

I have some music that I bought on iTunes that I'd like to have on my Linux computer. Is there a way I can install iTunes and download the music? I already tried using Wine, and I got a lot of errors, and the application's GUI didn't show properly, so Wine is out of the question. Is there any alternative other than repurchasing the music?

Comment: Have you tried older versions of iTunes been awhile since I have but I know I used to get iTunes working fine 2 years ago

Comment: Yeah, I just did. It just says that there's a later version of itunes installed, even though I deleted all of iTunes' stuff. Maybe I'll go to my Windows installation and put the music onto a thumb drive or something.

Comment: As sucky as it is, the easiest way seems to be to use a VM and re-map the itunes folder to one the host has access to, via a share for example.  Or use a different service to purchase music :)

Comment: I dual boot Windows and Linux, so maybe I'll just hop on to Windows and put my music onto a thumb drive or something like that.

Comment: If you can export the music, have you tried simply copying it onto your linux drive and playing it? Is that impossible because of some silly DRM stuff?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'll try doing. I don't know if iTunes has any "silly DRM stuff" anymore, though. I hope not.

Comment: @terdon I could copy my music to iTunes so I'm pretty sure there's no DRM. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can export your music from iTunes, the easiest thing to do would be to just save it in a partition that Linux has access to or a USB drive and then just copy it over to the Linux install.

Another approach would be to have Windows running in a virtual machine like VMWare or VirtualBox that way you can just fire up the VM whenever you want to use iTunes. That's what I do to sync all my iStuff™ from Linux.

Comment: I put my music on dropbox then copied it over. It worked, thanks.